# Replacing mcrypt_encrypt using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 with openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt, php-openssl

As you guys probably know, the extension mcrypt will be deprecated on php 7.1.

I use to maintain a "legacy" application that I want to migrate eventually to this version so I ran the tests and verified that I can't get 100% of coverage anymore, since there's a piece of code that use the following code:

```php
$key = 'sA*(DH';

// initialization vector
$iv = md5(md5($key));
$output = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string,     MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

I tried to port this piece of code to openssl_encrypt using this code

```php
$key = md5('sA*(DH');
$iv = md5($key);
echo base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
```

But I have 2 problems with this:

1. The IV lenght should be 16 chars (and md5 gives me 32), so I get a PHP Warning
2. The output it's not the same (even if I truncate to 16 chars)

Anyone had similar problems (or know how to fix it?)

BTW: I'm using the dev master version of PHP (supposed to be 7.1.0 alpha 3).

Answer (score 3):

Yet another tested solution taking and returning ANSI text to replace Mcrypt function with the openssl_encrypt() and openssl_decrypt():

```
//Return encrypted string
public function stringEncrypt ($plainText, $cryptKey = '7R7zX2Urc7qvjhkr') {

  $cipher   = 'aes-128-cbc';

  if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
  {
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(
      $plainText, $cipher, $cryptKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $cryptKey, $as_binary=true);
    $encodedText = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
  }

  return $encodedText;
}


//Return decrypted string
public function stringDecrypt ($encodedText, $cryptKey = '7R7zX2Urc7qvjhkr') {

  $c = base64_decode($encodedText);
  $cipher   = 'aes-128-cbc';

  if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
  {
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
    $ivlenSha2len = $ivlen+$sha2len;
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    $plainText = openssl_decrypt(
      $ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $cryptKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
  }

  return $plainText;
}
```

More read in [openssl documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should really get out of the habit of using md5 for anything.

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$key = substr(hash('sha256', 'sA*(DH'), 0, 32)
```

`mcrypt_encrypt` and `openssl_encrypt` will not output the same crypttext given the same plaintext and key.

also, `mcrypt` is deprecated in PHP 7.1, not removed...so you can update to 7.1 without changing from `mcrypt` to `openssl` ... but it is a good idea to remove `mcrypt` in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the original code is not mine and I really don't use md5 for nothing actually.

Gonna try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems :

1. MCrypt uses zero padding while Openssl uses by default PKCS#7
2. Openssl needs the input string to be of proper length (multiple of block length)

To solve this problems :

1. add OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING flag to openssl_encrypt/openssl_decrypt
2. if input string length is not multiple of block length then append to the input string zero chars "\0" [aka chr(0)];

That being said this should solve the problem:

```
// key/iv in ASCII binary data, $str base64
function decrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
    // $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($str), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $plaintext_dec = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($str), "aes-256-cbc", $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
    return $plaintext_dec;
}

// key/iv in ascii binary data, $str ascii
function encrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
    // $ciphertext = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    if (($l = (strlen($str) & 15)) > 0) { $str .= str_repeat(chr(0), 16 - $l); }
    $ciphertext = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, "aes-256-cbc", $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv));
    return $ciphertext;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Have you tried with $iv with 32 bytes long? The error I keep getting is that the IV is longer than the 16 bytes required and that the IV will be truncated.

Comment: The IV should have the same length with the block (in our case that is 16bytes) ... More details see here : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90848/encrypting-using-aes-256-can-i-use-256-bits-iv